# On the Weissinger's fixed point theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fixed-point-theorems

First we recall the following result (see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214242/weissingers-theorem-how-to-prove)):

**Weissinger's fixed point theorem**: Let $X$ be a complete metric space and assume that $f:X\longrightarrow X$ satisfies the following

$$
d(f^{i}(x),f^{i}(y))\leq \alpha_{i} d(x,y), \quad (*)
$$
for all $i\geq 1$, where $f^{i}$ stands for the composition of $f$ with itself $i$-times, and $\alpha_{i}$ is a sequence of non-negative numbers such that $\sum_{i\geq 1}\alpha_{i}<\infty$.

I am looking for an example (if any) of a continuous and not compact mapping $f:X\longrightarrow X$, $X$ being the closed unit ball of an infinite dimensional (real) Banach space such that:

(1) $f$ does not satisfy (*)

(2) $f^{i}$ is compact (i.e., $f^{i}$ maps bounded subsets into precompact ones) for some $i\geq 2$.

Of course, above $X$ can be replaced for any other convex and closed subset.

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Thanks!

Comment: Take any discontinuous map such that $f^2$ is constant. This can even be done with linear maps.

Comment: Thanks @MaoWao, but if $f$ is discontinuous, it does not sastify condition (*) with $i=1$.

Comment: But that is exactly what you want in (1), isn't it? In any case, I just saw you want a continuous $f$ ...

Comment: I haven't given this much thought, but what happens if you take $f$ to be a projection from an infinite dimensional Banach space to a finite-dimensional non-trivial subspace (and restrict to the closed unit ball, if you want)? I mean $d(f^i(x),f^i(y)) = d(x,y)$ for $x$ and $y$ in this subspace, so (*) is not satisfied, yet $f^i = f$ maps bounded sets to bounded sets of a finite dimensional space and these are definitely precompact. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Thanks for your response, but such $f$ is, itself, compact, and I am looking for a non-compact (but $f^{i}$ compact for some $i\geq 2$). I edit this detail in the post. Also, I am not sure that, in your context, $d(x,y)=d(f^{i}(x),f^{i}(y)))$. However, I will revise your comment, because it seems interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the spirit of the comment by Matthias Klupsch, you can also take something like
$$
Tx := (x_1, x_3, 0, x_5, 0, x_7, 0, \ldots )
$$
for $x \in \ell^2$.
Then, $T$ is not compact, but
$T^i x = (x_1, 0, \ldots)$ for $i \ge 2$ which is compact.
Moreover, the Lipschitz constant of $T^i$ is always $1$, hence, $\alpha_i \ge 1$.

Comment: Nice example!! Thanks.